# how can i access files/folders from other partitions and devices(flash drive) using ubuntu terminal?

Tags: partitioning, bash, hard-drive, directory, devices

What i want is to use terminal to access my entire hard drive and other devices using terminal. this is because i store most of my data in other partitions other than the home directory. i want to play music, videos and manipulate data contained in other partitions on my hard drive using terminal.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  I find it faster to access files from terminal than with gui, you just `mount` them & navigate to them (`cd` etc), then do whatever you want with them (eg. I use `cmus` to play music, though if you want to play a single file `mpg123`is faster as no UI to navigate) which can be done from anywhere (`ssh` into box). You may be asking how (how to use terminal, how to `mount` etc), what apps to use (eg. `cmus`, `mpg123` i used by example only) or something else?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsblk` with the external/additional drives connected and mounted? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To access them, you need to know where they are located. It sounds like you have multiple partitions, you can see where they are mounted using `lsblk`.  Here's an example of the output from that command on one of my systems.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   800M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 149.7G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 759.3G  0 part /media/Music
└─sda7   8:7    0    21G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1.4T  0 part /home
├─sdb2   8:18   0   200M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb4   8:20   0 482.2G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   1.7T  0 part /media/Movies
└─sdc2   8:34   0     2T  0 part /media/Pictures
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So if I wanted to play a music file located on partition `sda6`, I could either `cd` to `/media/Music` and look for it, or if I know it, I could use the full path in my music player `/media/Music/Blondie/Rip_Her_To_Shreds.mp3`

Comment: Wow!  you understood that from that question?  Upvoted!

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ took a shot.

Comment: You have to double the \ like this: `¯\\_(ツ)_/¯` which then gives this: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  **;-)**